# install burg theme in grub

Tags: grub2, themes, burg

I want to change the theme of GRUB using BURG theme,is it possible?

I do not want to install BURG in my MBR, just change the default 'GRUB' theme with BURG theme?

or stealing the BURG theme and then put it in the GRUB.

Comment: Why don't you want to use burg?

Comment: yeah, I think, would be better to install only one GRUB instead of installing the burg and grub. and if we do a 'sudo update-burg', we only use the burg's file (/boot/burg/burg.cfg) as a bootloader. GRUB is not used at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can't. You should use BURG for it. The only thing you can do is, changing GRUB's background with the themes' one. But you can't get OS icons etc. on GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

BURG's theme syntax is very similar to GRUB2's (because BURG's theme engine is a fork of GRUB2's). Ports of many popular BURG  themes are available in this tar.gz: jordanu.dyndns.org/grub/themes.tgz and two themes created specifically for GRUB2 are available here: http://apebox.org/wordpress/linux/261/ .